# segmented controls type in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, uisegmentedcontrol

I try to make buttons like those on the desk of android:

[image]

This button are similar to the uisegmentedcontrol for Iphone. I don't find a easy way to do this in Android.

For the moment, I use the Button explain here:

http://blog.bookworm.at/2010/10/segmented-controls-in-android.html

But the result seems not so good compared to the desk button. There is no round corner, alpha, etc...

Is there an easy way to use the same button than the desk button?

Answer (score 14):

You could try implementing the code used by this brilliant developer:

https://github.com/makeramen/android-segmentedradiobutton

Helped me a great deal!!!

Comment: thanks. 
That's was parfectly what I was searching for but that's too late. I'v already develop my own radiobutton with the same technique even if they don't looks so good

Comment: I am glad it helped. Would you be so kind as to mark the tick by the side of the answer so folks can know if it is the right one or not?Thanks